# Quick Moon-or-Sun Puzzles: 2x1-Dominoes and 1x1-Checkerboards

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

[image]

> **Moon-or-Sun** (adapted from [Nikoli](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/moon-or-sun.html))
>
> - Draw a line to make a single loop.
> - Lines pass through the centers of cells, horizontally, vertically, or turning. The loop never crosses itself, branches off, or goes through the same cell twice.
> - A rectangle, bordered by bold lines, is called a "room".
> - Color each room blue or yellow.
> - The loop must visit each room once, alternating between blue and yellow rooms.
> - In a blue room, you must visit all of the moons and none of the suns; in a yellow room, you must visit all of the suns and none of the moons.

Comment: Seeing the misunderstanding and all that, I'd like to ask clearly: passing through a room WITHOUT a sun or moon counts as part of the sequence? (Ex: Can't go moon-moon but can go moon-blank-moon?)

Comment: A suggestion for rephrasing the rules to account for empty rooms: "Color each room blue or yellow. Draw a loop visiting each room once, alternating between blue and yellow rooms. In a blue room, you must visit all of the moons and none of the sums; in a yellow room, you must visit all of the suns and none of the moons."

Comment: Welp, got to admit that indeed the original rules may confuse the solver when they are given empty room. For @Belhenix , that's correct: can't go moon-moon but moon-blank-moon is okay (if the second room doesn't contain any sun). And Deusovi , I like and agree with the suggestion, will update the rules accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the answer to the first one

> [image]

And here is the second one

> [image]

Comment: And yep, they are the correct answers!